# Nginx as reverse proxy for apache with ssl

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

For now I have apache setup with ssl (users use private certificates).

Is it possible to put apache behind nginx in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-setup-nginx-ssl-proxy/

Also look at pound - http://www.apsis.ch/pound/
as an alternative or in addition to (in front of) nginx.

Comment: I've read that article. And as you can see - apache there listens port 80, not 443.

Comment: Even though it is not an answer - I'll check it as long as I just don't like having not accepted answers (and because it is very likely no one will ever read this question ;-) )